# py.magic in py.test 2.0.2

Tags: python, testing

In py.test 2.0.2, What do we use in place of

```
py.magic.autopath().dirpath()
```

since 'py.magic' has been removed after py-1.0.2

Comment: What does "py.magic" actually do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(**file**))

// gives the parent directory of the current file.